# Setting FrameworkElement.DataContext to an anonymous object

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I have this grid, containing a template:

```
<Grid x:Name="Bar" Width="400">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="ScoreText">
            <Grid Grid.Column="{Binding Col}">
                <Rectangle Fill="Red"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid
```

I want to insert an instance of the template into the containing grid, `Bar`. Here's what I'm doing:

```
FrameworkElement item = (FrameworkElement) ScoreText.LoadContent();
item.DataContext = new { Col = 0, Value = 100 };
Bar.Children.Add(item);
```

This works in the XAML designer in visual studio, but fails to bind correctly on the phone.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried not using anonymous object? Normally, I'd define a type with properties http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx and then set the dataContex to Grid http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx

Comment: @lukas: defining a simple type didn't help: `public struct Data { public int Col; public string Value; }`, although I realize now that the type conversion are probably important. Now it doesn't even work in the designer. What do you mean by `set the dataContex to `Grid`? Which grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anonymous types don't work, since only properties can be bound to. Adding:

```
public struct Data {
    public int Col {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

And changing

```
item.DataContext = new { Col = 0, Value = 100 };
```

to

```
item.DataContext = new Data { Col = 0, Value = 100 };
```

makes it work

Comment: It's better to change it to class. Mutable structs are evil ;)